# Group Timestamps into intervals of 5 minutes, take value that's closest to timestamp and always give out a value

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to SQL coding and would heavily appreciate help for a problem I'm facing. I have the following SQL script, that gives me the following output (see picture 1):

```
WITH speicher as(
select a.node as NODE_ID, d.name_0 as NODE_NAME, d.parent as PARENT_ID, c.time_stamp as ZEITSTEMPEL,  c.value_num as WERT, b.DESCRIPTION_0 as Beschreibung, TO_CHAR(c.time_stamp, 'HH24:MI:SS') as Uhrzeit
from p_value_relations a, l_nodes d,  p_values b, p_value_archive c 
where a.node in (select sub_node from l_node_relations r where r.node in (
                                           50028,
                                           49989,
                                           49848
                                           
 ))
and a.node = d.id
and (b."DESCRIPTION_0" like 'Name1' OR b."DESCRIPTION_0" like 'Name2')
and c.time_stamp between SYSDATE-30 AND SYSDATE-1
and a.value = b.id and b.id =  c.value)

SELECT WERT as Value, NODE_NAME, ZEITSTEMPEL as Timestamp, Uhrzeit as Time, Beschreibung as Category
FROM speicher
```

I would like to create time intervals of 5 minutes to output the value. It should always choose the value closest above one on the defined time interval time stamps. If there is no value inside a set 5 minute intervall it should still give out the last value it finds, since the value has not changed in that case. To see what I mean please see the following picture. Any help wold be greatly appreciated. This data is from an oracle database.

Result until now [[image: 1]
Result I would like[image: 2]

Comment: Please post table definition and data as text. This will save time for those who want to code a solution for you.

Comment: which database are you using time functions differ

Comment: @LeoFrittrang - It's important to specify which dbms you're using because sql syntax can vary a LOT by vendor and version. I added `Oracle` to question tags based on the sql syntax and screen shot. Please update if that's not correct.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, you are right it is an oracle database

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not understand your data, and can't test with it, I present something I could test with. My data has a table which tracks when folks login to a system.

This is not intended as a complete answer, but as something to potentially point you in the right direction;

```
with time_range
as
(
  select rownum, sysdate - (1/288)*rownum time_stamp
  from dual
  connect By Rownum <= 288*30
)
select time_stamp, min(LOGIN_TIME) 
from time_range
left outer join WEB_SECURITY_LOGGED_IN on LOGIN_TIME >= time_stamp
group by time_stamp
order by 1;
```

Good luck...

Edit:

The with part of the query builds a time_stamp column which has one row for every 5 minutes for the last 30 days. The query portion joins to my login log table which I get the login which is the smallest date/time greater than the time_stamp.